# Why can't I obtain values of Sine/Cosine with $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}?$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Taking into account the circle equation $ x^2 + y^2 = 1$, I've made the following function on Mathematica : $ f (x) = \sqrt {1 - x^2}$ which yields this plot with the domain $ 0\leq x\leq 1$ :

[image]

I' ve made an animated gif of this :

[image]

Which seems pretty reasonable to yield the values for sine and cosine.But then $ f (1/2) = \frac {\sqrt {3}} {2}$ which should yield the Sin/Cos of 45 degrees, but it gets different of the value given by Mathematica when using the Cos and Sin functions ($\sin 45 = \cos 45 = \frac {1} {\sqrt {2}}$), So what's hapenning?

---

### Notes:

- I've read somewhere that the problem is that Sine is supposed to take an angle as an input and that my function takes a length as input. When I wrote Sine/Cosine I actually tried to express the points $(x,y)$ on the circle, I thought they were the same because of [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg) - so if length is different of angle, perhaps one could find those points with with the function I provided, but it would have a different meaning.
- I'm aware of the existence of trigonometric functions in Calculus, but at the current moment, I know nothing about them.
- The function seems to be not that similar to sine and cosine functions (as one can see [here for example](http://www.geogebra.org/en/upload/files/Mandrejkovics/Sin_and_Cos_from_Unit_Circle.html)) but I feel it could be adapted to such task.

Comment: You've got $x=\cos\theta$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin\theta$.  Your function takes $\cos\theta$ rather than $\theta$ as its input.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ means in terms of sine and cosine:

$$f(\cos(\phi))=\sqrt{1-\cos(\phi)^2}=|\sin(\phi)|$$

where $\phi=\arccos(1/2)=\pi/3=60^°$, not $45^°$. Indeed, $\sin(\phi)=\sin(\pi/3)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

In general, the equation $f(x)=y$ expresses that the point $(x,y)$ lies on the upper unit semicircle at the angle $\phi=\arccos(x)=\arcsin(y)$.

Comment: What do you think about my first note? Do you think that this function would work to find the points $(x,y)$ on the circle? I'm thinking that perhaps this is a way of finding the points based on length, not angle. What do you think?

Comment: @PristineKavalostka Yes this function generates points on the circle: $f(x)$ gives you the correct value for $y$ such that $(x,y)$ lies on the (upper half) of the unit circle.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka Your function doesn't take "a length" as input, it takes the $x$-coordinate of the corresponding point on the unit circle as an input.

Comment: One curiosity: If this gives the location of the point in the perimeter of the circle, why isn't this used to get values for the Sine and Cosine? In the image I provided, it says that the Sine is the vertical coordinate of the point, and the cosine is the horizontal coordinate. I've found both with my formula, no? I'm confused about what's the difference between them.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka It *does* give the value of sine and cosine. But the function does *not* give the *angle* which you have to plug into sine and cosine to get this point. To recover the angle you can use any reverse trig function.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka You know if you have some $x$ coordinate. Then you can calculate $y=f(x)$ and you then know that $(x,y)$ is on the unit circle. On the other hand, also *every point* on the unit circle is of the form $(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$ for some angle $\phi$... that means $x=\cos(\phi)$, $f(x)=y=\sin(\phi)$, so $f(x)$ is the value of sine at the angle of the point $(x,f(x))$.

Comment: Now it makes sense: $\sin \theta= \frac{Opp(\theta)}{Hyp(\theta)}$, the hypotenuse in this case was always 1. Then I was doing $\frac{f(x)}{1}=f(x)$. The idea of having to use the reverse trig function to get the angle is a revolution to me. Thanks. You taught me more trigonometry with the answer and comments than my school in 3 years.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka That's what I like to hear :-).

Comment: There's just one more thing I still couldn't connect: Why do they say that the [sine is the vertical coordinate and the cosine is the horizontal coordinate?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sin-cos-defn-I.png) I got stuck for a lot of time because I believed this was true. But actually - just as you said - the formulation is a little different.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka: No, actually it's exactly like that. The $x$ coordinate (i.e. the horizontal coordinate) is cosine, and $y$ coordinate (the vertical coordinate) is sine.

Comment: Then I'm confused. If sine is the vertical coordinate and cosine is the horizontal one, why can't I assume that $\sin 45=f(1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$? Your answer and comments shown me that one needs to use this value in a reverse trig function to obtain the angle and then obtain the sine. Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: Why would you think that point is at $45^\circ$? It is **not**. It is at $60^\circ$. @PristineKavalostka

Answer (score 2):

Your function plots a semi-circle above the $x$ axis. The $x$ value you specify **is** $\cos(\theta)$ for some value of $\theta$, and the resulting value $f(x)$ **is** $\sin(\theta)$ for that same value of $\theta$. You should find that for a given value of $x\in[-1,1]$ the corresponding value of $\theta$ is $$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right).$$

For example, $$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}{\cos\theta} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta,$$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

You've got $x=\cos\theta$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin\theta$.  When $x=1/2$, then $\cos\theta=1/2$, meaning you've got a $60^\circ$ angle. The sine of $60^\circ$ is $\sqrt{3}/2$.